Why is the site now using a domain sstatic.net instead of imugur?
I have noticed this change in uploaded images.
Was there a problem? Will all the images be updated? or simply the new ones will live there and the old ones in the old house?
I am assuming this change affects all the Stack Exchange sites.

See this post on Meta SE.

Annoying since you can't link to images posted here on other sites. The change essentially means image links posted to SE are only good at SE, and blocked everywhere else.
